# fixture 'httpbin' not found

Tags: python, python-requests, pytest

I start reading python `requests` library.
The first thing I do is run pytest locally.

Then I got this error message:

```
  @pytest.fixture
  def httpbin(httpbin):
    fixture 'httpbin' not found
    available fixtures: tmpdir_factory, httpbin_secure, pytestconfig, httpbin, cov, cache, recwarn, monkeypatch, record_xml_property, capfd, capsys, tmpdir
    use 'py.test --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.
```

In the `conftest.py` file in the tests module, it tries to create a fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture
def httpbin(httpbin):
    return prepare_url(httpbin)
```

how could you create a httpbin fixture by using httpbin fixture?
What did I miss?

Comment: Why do you call both the method an argument `httpbin`?

Comment: @LutzHorn: the code is from requests conftest.py. it is trying to create a fixture called `httpbin` by using a fixture `httpbin`. and this is my source of confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `httpbin` fixture is provided by the [`pytest-httpbin`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-httpbin) package. So you need to make sure that you installed the required **dependencies for running tests / building docs** before running the tests.

This basically amounts to `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

In a bit more detail, installing everything into a virtualenv:

```sh
# Create the virtualenv
$ virtualenv-2.7 --no-site-packages requests-env
$ cd requests-env
$ . bin/activate

# Make sure your venv's version of setuptools is up to date
(requests-env) $ pip install -U setuptools

# Clone a copy of the requests module
(requests-env) $ mkdir src
(requests-env) $ cd src/
(requests-env) $ git clone git@github.com:kennethreitz/requests.git

# Install required dependencies
(requests-env) $ cd requests/
(requests-env) $ pip install -r requirements.txt
(requests-env) $ pip install mock

# Run tests
(requests-env) $ py.test
```

---

(Note: `pip install mock` should only be required for Python < 3.3)